# What does /**/ mean in css?

Tags: css

I've got the following in some CSS, probably introduced by Sylizer (and the new version is now complaining about it):

```
/*Disabling quote effect in IE5 +*/
   background /**/: url("bungalow_copy(1).css");
```

What does  /**/  mean?

Comment: It is a comment.  The browser ignores everything inside the `/* */` symbols.

Comment: /* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue } from http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a comment, see [CSS3 syntax: 4.10. Comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#comments).

You can add additional information in a comment, for example to remind you of certain fixes for some browsers or some special effects which were hard to achieve:

```
/* The basic class for styling */
.basic{
   color: blue;
   border: 1px solid; /* take text color */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anything enclosed by `/**/` is a comment, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

That means it is a comment. So if you wrap `/**/` around something it is commented out.

Ex: `/* You are awesome */` it will appear grey or whatever color your editor is set to for comments

Comment: Use backticks (\`) to mark code, eg: \`/**/\` -> `/**/`

Comment: A comment may appear gray in your favorite editor, but some of us don't use fancy syntax highlighting editors…

Comment: Touche @Zeta . I never thought of that haha

Answer (score 1):

In general, anything between `/*` and `*/` is a comment, and is therefore completely ignored by the browser.

At least, it should be. In this case, it looks like the empty comment is designed to be a browser hack to make something "work".